# How to extract only numeric data from a sqlite?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I have a table in a sqlite with one column "A"

```
A
1
2
3
INF
```

The column "A" is defined as numeric. But it was read it from R so the INF was the R code for infinite.

How to obtain the max of A using SQLite sql? I tried

```
select
   max(a)
from
   table
where a != INF
```

and

```
select
   max(a)
from
   table
where a != "INF"
```

As you can see I noob at SQLite.

Comment: Not seeing anything wrong with your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/eea1f/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like 9e999 for `Inf`, e.g.,

```
select
   max(a)
from
   table
where a != 9e999
```

Answer (score -1):

Extending on the answer by Matthew Plourde
How about

```
select
   max(a)
from
   table
where a < 9e999
```